# Is it possible to add custom demux or decoder to playbin2

Tags: gstreamer, playbin2

I am working on a rmvb playback plugin on gstreamer.I write the demux and decoders,and it work fine when I link them using pipeline.

But the playback application is using the playbin2 to play the videos.
so I wonder if it is possible to add them to the playbin2. so that playbin2 can play rmvb files.

But I dont know what to do.
So my question is:

1.Is it possible to do that;

2.If it is possible , what are the keywords I should search;

3.If it is impossible . is there any other way to play the rmvb file at the least cost.(It is hard to change the playback application source code)

It will be appreciated if any one helps.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

1. Yes
2. Elements have ranks, playbin will look for the elements with the highest rank to be used. So you need to make sure your element reports rmvb caps (as reported by gst-typefind) on its sink pads and that it has a high enough rank. Ranks are set when registering the element to the plugin.
3. There should already be rmvb support in gstreamer, maybe you're just missing the proper plugin in your installation? You shouldn't need to write a new one. It should be in gst-plugins-ugly (realmedia is the name of the plugin IIRC).
4. Unasked but **please move to 1.0**, **0.10 is dead/obsolete/unmantained for years now**. By using it you won't be getting much or any help from the community these days.

Comment: Thanks a lot , I know that to do now. My rmvb plugin made some optimization for my hardware.so I have to write a new one.